# How to use PowerMTA with PHP

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to use PHP to send emails, process bounces and feedback loops, get delivery statistics with PowerMTA? Can PowerMTA handle all these tasks?
We plan to create a system for email marketing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a service like [Postmark](http://postmarkapp.com) that does all this for you?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it. 
But it looks like people I work with want to user PowerMTA.

Answer (score 1):

Yes PowerMTA can use PHP to send and monitor delivery.  Let me know if you'd like me to set you up on an evaluation...

thanks.
\fred

Answer (score 0):

just use Message Systems Momentum platform and save yourself a ton of time having to write a ton of custom code with powermta